# Error while implementing progress_bar in pytube3

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am implementing a youtube video downloader using pytube3. In the following `progress_bar()` function I am getting an `positional argument` missing error.

> My progress_bar() function:

```
def progress_bar(stream, chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    file_downloaded = file_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage = (file_downloaded / file_size) * 100
    print(f'{percentage :00.0f}% done...')
```

> My YouTube() object:

```
yt_object = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=progress_bar)
```

I am getting the following error while displaying or printing the progress

`progress_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bytes_remaining'`

The file is being downloaded successfully if I do remove the progress_bar reference in YouTube object i.e. yt_object, but I am facing the error in implementing progress_bar().

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. Solved it by this way:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.cli import on_progress

def download_video(url):
    yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    stream = yt.streams.first()
    print("start to download url: " + url)
    print(stream.title)
    stream.download(DOWNLOAD_DIR)
```